# PCB GND Guard ring

Tags: pcb, emc, switching, step-up

In my design I am using the step-up converter [TLV61046a](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fds%2Fsymlink%2Ftlv61046a.pdf). As this is the switching device, I would like to maximize EMI reduction. I would like to hear your advice if this GND guard ring in my layout make any sense in EMI reduction. The following are the pictures of the step-up converter part:

[image] 
[image]

The idea for the GND guard ring comes from the [MCU 32768Hz crystal layout](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/t/312483) tips, but I am not sure if this can make any good for my application. It is just me experimenting, not official advice. Should I leave it, or remove it?

Comment: I don't think it ever hurts to have a guard ring...as long as you can fit one in. But it should only be grounded on one end, lest it become a loop antenna. And in this case, wouldn't just have a grounded copper fill do the same thing?

Comment: That guard ring will have no effect on EMI. It is much more important to have a solid ground plane layer, minimize the inductance of switching paths and have have proper filtering on the input and output.

Comment: @Toor: Wouldn't grounding only one end essentially form a patch antenna, which is even less desireable?

Comment: You know what? I might be confusing it with cable shielding. But as others have mentioned, the only time I have ever seen guard rings mentioned is to protect high impedance pins from leakage currents. It seems it should also be a fully enclosed ring which isn't the same as what I remembered. It seems there are different approaches.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a ground plane, then the guard ring will have little impact.
Guard rings are usually to protect high impedance inputs like specialized op-amps, not so much for EMI radiation.

[National Semiconductor Application Note 241](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa664/snoa664.pdf)

> ELECTRICAL GUARDING
>
> The effects of board leakage can be minimized using an old trick known as guarding. Here the input circuitry is
> surrounded by a conductive trace that is connected to a low impedance
> point at the same potential as the inputs. The electrical connection
> of the guard for the basic op amp configurations is shown in Figure 5.
> The guard absorbs the leakage from other points on the board,
> drastically reducing that reaching the input circuitry. To be
> completely effective, there should be a guard ring on both sides of
> the printed-circuit board. It is still recommended for single-sided
> boards, but what happens on the unguarded side is difficult to analyze
> unless Teflon inserts are used on the input leads. Further, although
> surface leakage can be virtually eliminated, the reduction in bulk
> leakage is much less. The reduction in bulk leakage for double-sided
> guarding is about an order of magnitude, but this depends on board
> thickness and the width of the guard ring. If there are bulk leakage
> problems, Teflon inserts on the through holes and Teflon or kel-F
> standoffs for terminations can be used. These two materials have
> excellent surface properties without surface treatment even in
> high-humidity environments.
> [image]

In fact, if you have the guard ring close to a high current node, it can pick up that noise and radiate it like an antenna.

Again, for best EMI performance, a good solid ground plane, with lots of ground via connections is best. eg. Don't use a single 20mil via when you can use two or three 10 mill vias.

Answer (score 0):

This type of guarding is better done with plane fills to *increase capacitance* amongst component, there is a good [tutorial on this](https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/problems-solutions/the-dc-dc-boost-converter-part-3-power-supply-design-tutorial-section-5-3) for reference. In short group like components and planes. It also helps to have planes like this to have thermal relief for parts.

[image]
Source: https://www.powerelectronicsnews.com/problems-solutions/the-dc-dc-boost-converter-part-3-power-supply-design-tutorial-section-5-3